# $f: I→R$ continuous at a;$ g(x)=xf(x)$ is differentiable at a. Prove $f$ is differentiable at a.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let I be an interval, f:$I\rightarrow R$ is continuous at $a$; $g(x)=xf(x)$ and is differentiable at $a$. Prove f is also differentiable at $a$.

What I tried to do, looking at similar threads on this site, was apply the definition of the derivative.

Let $g'(a)=\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}\rightarrow$ Substitute on $g(x)=xf(x)$

$g'(a)=\frac{(a+h)f(a+h)-af(a)}{h}\rightarrow$ Distributive Property

$g'(a)=\frac{af(a+h)+hf(a+h)-af(a)}{h}\rightarrow$ Isolate a

$g'(a)=\frac{a[f(a+h)-f(a)]+hf(a+h)}{h}\rightarrow$ Divide the second half by $h$ and then apply $\lim_{h\to 0}$

$g'(a)=\frac{a[f(a+h)-f(a)]}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h)$

$g'(a)=af'(a)+f(a)$

I tried to argue that $f$ is continuous at both sides of $a$, so it has a derivate at $a$ but then realized it's not necessarily true. I don't know how to prove it anymore.

Comment: This isn't true if $a=0$ (for example, $f(x)=x^{1/3}$). I think it is true if $a \neq 0$.

Comment: Can't you just use the quotient rule? (Also assuming $a \neq 0$)

Answer (score 1):

As @aschepler points out, the proposition isn't true if $a=0$. Because $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at $a=0$, while $g(x) = x f(x) = x^{4/3}$ is differentiable at $0$.

If $a \neq 0$, you can apply the quotient rule to $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x}$. Then
$$
    f'(a) = \frac{a g'(a) - g(a)}{a^2} 
          = \frac{g'(a)-f(a)}{a}
$$

Your argument assumes that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ (just like many heuristic “proofs” of the quotient rule do).